# My event listener is not working, but upon checking my code on my other HTML file, it's the same. It won't insert any data records on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My event listener is not working and upon checking my other HTML code, this is the same code that I used. Here is my code, what's the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Agriculminate</title>
   <!-- Font Awesome -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/css/adminlte.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/css/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../asset/tables/datatables-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"> 
     <style type="text/css">
     
     aside.main-sidebar{
         background-color: #ddd;
         color:rgb(77, 75, 75);
      }
      nav ul li a p{
         color:rgb(41,74,43);
      }
      td a.btn{
                  font-size: 0.7rem;
               }
               td p{
                  padding-left: 0.5rem !important;
               }
               th{
                  padding: 1rem !important;
               }
               table tr td {
                  padding: 0.3rem !important;
                  font-size: 13px;
               }
               .bg1{
                  background-color: rgb(109,156,69);
                  color: rgb(211, 209, 207);
               }
               .c1{
                  color: rgb(255,165,0);
               }
               .c2{
                  color: rgb(226,121,121);
               }
   </style>
</head>

<body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-light" style="background-color: rgb(109,156,69)">
         <!-- Left navbar links -->
         <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button">
                  <img src="../asset/img/profile.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image" width="40" style="margin-top: -8px;">
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" data-widget="fullscreen" href="#" role="button">
                  <i class="fas fa-expand-arrows-alt"></i>
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" data-widget="fullscreen" href="../index.html">
                  <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-light-primary">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="index.html" class="brand-link">
         <img src="../asset/img/i.png" alt="Logo" width="70" style="margin-top: -75px;margin-bottom: -75px">

         </a>
         <div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="mt-2">
               <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu"
                  data-accordion="false">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/das.png" width="40">
                        <p style="color: rgb(77, 75, 75)">
                           Dashboard
                        </p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="crop.html" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/c.png" width="40">
                        <p>
                           Crop
                        </p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="fertilizer.html" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/fert.jpg" width="40">
                        <p>
                           Fertilizer
                        </p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="member.html" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/member.png" width="40">
                        <p>
                           Members
                        </p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="farm.html" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/d.png" width="40">
                        <p>
                           Farms
                        </p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="weather.php" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/b.jpeg" width="40">
                        <p>
                           Weather forecast
                        </p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="soil-analysis.html" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/a.png" width="40">
                        <p>
                           Soil Analysis 
                        </p>
                     </a>
                     </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                     <a href="yield.html" class="nav-link">
                        <img src="../asset/img/y.png" width="40">
                        <p>
                           Yield Documenter 
                        </p>
                     </a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
      </aside>
      <div class="content-wrapper">
         <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="row mb-2">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                     <h1 class="m-0" style="color:rgb(107,155,64);"><img src="../asset/img/cr.png" width="40"> Crop Information </h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                     <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Crop </li>
                     </ol>
                  </div>
                  <a class="btn btn-sm" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add"
                     style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;background-color: rgb(109,156,69)"><i
                        class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
                     Add New</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="card card-info elevation-2">
                  <br>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                     <table id="example1" class="table">
                        <thead class="btn-cancel">
                           <tr>
                              <th>Crop Name</th>
                              <th>Description</th>
                              <th>Action</th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td>Food crops</td>
                              <td>for human needs (e.g. wheat, maize, legumes, rice, potatoes, tomatoes).</td>
                              <td> <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash c2" title="delete"></i></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td>Feed crops</td>
                              <td>for cattle or livestock consumption (e.g. barley, beets, grasses for domestic animals to graze and store as hay or silage).</td>
                               <td> <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash c2" title="delete"></i></td>                           
                            </tr>
                           <tr>
                              <td>Fiber crops</td>
                              <td>  for the sake of fibers used in clothes, bedding, industry, and household (hemp, cotton, flax, bamboo).</td>
                             <td> <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash c2" title="delete"></i></td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="delete" class="modal animated rubberBand delete-modal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
               <img src="../asset/img/sent.png" alt="" width="50" height="46">
               <h3>Are you sure want to delete this Crop?</h3>
               <div class="m-t-20">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="map" class="modal animated rubberBand delete-modal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
               <form>
         <div class="card-footer">
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="add" class="modal animated rubberBand delete-modal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-md">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
               <form>
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                           <div class="card-header">
                              <h5><img src="../asset/img/cr.png" width="60"> Crop Information</h5>
                           </div>
                           <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="float-left">Crop Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" id = "cropName" class="form-control" placeholder="Crop Name">
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-12">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="float-left">Description</label>
                                    <textarea id = "cropInformation" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.card-body -->
                  <div class="card-footer">
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                     <button id = "addCrop" class="btn bg1">Save</button>
                  </div>
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- jQuery -->
   <script src="../asset/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../asset/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../asset/js/adminlte.js"></script>
   <!-- DataTables  & Plugins -->
   <script src="../asset/tables/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../asset/tables/datatables-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../asset/tables/datatables-responsive/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../asset/tables/datatables-buttons/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
 
</body>

 <script type="module">
 // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-database.js";
  import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.14.0/firebase-auth.js";

  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyChorY86hQnM_4NDlh1bAgPgcZhwNceAws",
    authDomain: "projectthesis-2e318.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://projectthesis-2e318-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
    projectId: "projectthesis-2e318",
    storageBucket: "projectthesis-2e318.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "823795590464",
    appId: "1:823795590464:web:cdddaa93724a81a21d06a5"
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
  const auth = getAuth();
  const database = getDatabase(app);


//Add to firebase database----------------

  addCrop.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

   var crops = document.getElementById('cropName').value;
   var cropDetails = document.getElementById('cropInformation').value;
   //const newKey = push(child(ref(database), 'crops')).key;

  set(ref(database, 'crops/' + cropsName), {
    cropsName: crops,
    cropDetails: cropDetails,

  }).then(() => {
  alert('Crop entry added successfully!');
})
.catch((error) => {
   const errorCode = error.code;
   const errorMessage = error.message;
  alert(errorMessage);
});

  });
  

   </script>

</html>
```

I tried, but upon clicking the save button, it doesnt do anything. I tried removing the code and just adding an alert it works, but upon adding the insert function, it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay here's what you do: Start by opening the developer panel in your web browser (typically by pressing F12) place a breakpoint right next to addCrop.addEventListener, and make sure your code is getting there. If that works, next put a breakpoint at the start of the anonymous click function and make sure that when you click the save button, it hits the breakpoint

Comment: I tried adding an alert("test"); on the first part of the code above set(ref(database, 'crops/' + cropsName). It did trigger, but the code below doesn't work.

Comment: ... doesn't work - did you step through it? Did you get an error message, or it just didn't work?

Comment: My debugging alert("test") works, but the code below don't work. Nothing happens not even an error message. Context: I want to add a data on the database. My register account and login works, I'm just really unsure why this won't work.

Comment: Local debugging is the most effective way to help yourself, or to make it likely that we can efficiently help you. Don't tell us what you did, but do what @ControlAltDel said and run in a debugger. So: if you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared (yes, that's a lot, because you shared a lot of code), run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I tried it, well it pauses in certain parts, but upon setting up a break point in this part  set(ref(database, 'crops/' + cropsName), it entirely skips it and it doesnt pause.